# How can I grep for broken HTML tags?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, html

I want to grep through all my HTML files and see if I have any bad tags there,
example `<br>` , `<hr>` and so on, that is the I want to see what tags are not closed in the HTML file.

```
for htmlFile in `ls -f *.html ` ; do
        if `cat $htmlFile | grep -inE "\<br\>"` ; then
           echo "In file $htmlFile there are errors on the following lines: "  >> ~/Desktop/$1_errors.txt
           cat $htmlFile | grep -in "<br>"| cut -d ":" -f1 >> ~/Desktop/$1_errors.txt
           echo "----------------------------------------" >> ~/Desktop/$1_errors.txt
       fi
done
```

But I get an error, I am suspect its my regex.

```
./script.sh: line 14: 10:<BR: command not found
```

That is one of the error I get :)

Comment: Uh-oh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: See also [this site](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for why you shouldn't be parsing the output of `ls` in this case.

Comment: I have tried using `shopt -s nullglob` but I dont know how to undo shopt

Comment: "I get an error" exactly which error?

Comment: `line 14: 1:<BR: command not found`
That is one of them :)

Comment: @Caleb Why did you delete your answer? 
I tried using tidy and I liked it :O

Comment: 1) Don't use regex to parse HTML 2) Never use `for` loops with `ls` (and avoid parsing ls in general) 3) Don't `cat file | grep`, just `grep file`.

Comment: To be clear: you are only looking for specific tags that should be <x/> but are actually <x>, right? You're not trying to find tags (e.g. <div>) that are opened but not closed?

Comment: Thank you guys, I am really new to this and I am learning a lot here :)

Comment: @Benubird Yes, I am trying to find tags that are not closed in general. about <div> that is a tricky one, but it would be good to have it included :)

Comment: Then forget it, you will never be able to do it correctly using grep. You need something more sophisticated.

Comment: @terdon Can you provide a link explaining this? I had a quick search, but I couldn't find a page showing why it was impossible. I know it is (this is analogous to the nested-brackets problem), but it would be useful to have a link here to an article explaining why.

Comment: Have a look at the link given by goldilocks in the 1st comment. Also, just think about it. Consider the differences between XHTML and HTML. For example, `</br>` is not needed in the latter and there are various other tags that don't need closing tags. How would you deal with nested tags? The whole thing is just way too complex for regular expressions.

Comment: @Unknown I removed my answer because I thought I'd misread your question, it turns out your formatting was just confusing.

Comment: I apologize for that. I am really new to all this. And I am still learning :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem(s) are in this line:

```
if `cat $htmlFile | grep -inE "\<br\>"` ; then
```

It's telling the shell to:

- cat a file,
- parse it and look for lines that match the `<br>` tag,
- **execute the output**

The problem is the last step, you shouldn't execute the output of the command but test it:

```
if grep -inEq "\<br\>" $htmlFile ; then
```

Of course, to parse HTML you should use a real parser, no regexes.

Answer (score 8):

Even if you fix the errors in your shell syntax as [Braiam's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136594/1925) correctly identifies, you will *never* get this to really work right. At best you might find a few mistakes of the sort you know you make; but you will never get grep to reliably find broken tags of the sort you might not have already noticed you are breaking.

To do this right you need to use something that actually parses and understands HTML tags. There are lots of HTML validation tools out there that can point out where you have broken tag syntax. One of the most common that you should start by checking out is `tidy`. In particular try running it on your files with this flag:

```
 -errors, -e         show only errors and warnings
```

This will point out where you have broken tags such as things that are not closed the way they should be to comply with your doctype.

There are also lots of other options besides tidy for doing syntax checking on HTML. Using the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is a good one. Whatever you do—at the risk of the computer gods [raining fire and brimstone on you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)—don't even try to parse html syntax with regular expressions like grep uses for pattern matching.